# get content of wysiwyg editor and send it to html

Tags: php, html

I am messing around with WYSIWYG-Editors and would like to get the current content of it with php and append it to html or lets say a `<p>`.
I have to say that I am a PHP-beginner, but i've figured out how to get the content of a `.txt` and `echo` it to my html.

```
<?php
    $textfile = "text.txt";
    $text = file($textfile);
    echo $text 
?>
```

very simple. But there must be a possibility to "replace" the `text.txt` with a wysiwyg-editor.

Does anyone of you have a hint, i would really appreciate that.

Thanks

**Edit:** In Detail that means, i have a website `index.html`, with some text-content. I don't want to use a `CMS` but kind of a other html which can the user access `textedit.html` and type some sentences in a `WYSIWYG` editor like `CK-Editor` or `TinyMCE`. `textedit.html` accesses the `index.html` and changes a defined `<p>` tag.

Comment: There is not enough info provided, please specify what editor are you using and what have you tried so far. From what you are saying so far it looks like it would be easier to get content from WYSIWYG editor using Java Script library and append it to a new paragraph. Yet that depends on the situation in which you want to use it, if its local editor or external and so on.

Comment: i have made an edit to the op where i explain it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the editor will come in most cases from a POST Request of a form.

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="text" id="editor"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And then in `process.php`:

```
<?php
$content = $_POST['text'];
echo $content;
?>
```

Of course you have to add some validation to this. However this should give you a simple idea and get you started.

You can also start a google search like this: "form processing php".

### EDIT

You need some kind of server-side action to do this. This is not possible with pure HTML! You need to add a server-side backend.

Just a little diagramm to illustrate this:

editor.html
| sends changes to backend
v
backend (changes the contents of the frontend)
|
v
content.html

This is a very poor design (to change the contents of the html file directly) but the principal is the same. In "good" setups you would have a database which holds the contents and the frontend would pull from there and the backend pushes. But with pure HTML this is not possible!

So let me give you some boilerplate:

index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- add more stuff here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Your Site</h1>
        <!-- add more stuff here -->
        <p>
        <?php
        echo file_get_contents('article.txt');
        ?>
        </p>
        <!-- add more stuff here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

editor.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- add more stuff here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Your Site - Editor</h1>
        <!-- add more stuff here -->
        <form action="process.php" method="POST">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password..." />
            <textarea name="text" id="editor"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <!-- add more stuff here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

process.php:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['text']) {
    die('Please fill out the form at editor.html');
}
if($_POST['pwd'] !== 'your_password') {
    die('Password incorrect');
}
file_put_contents('article.txt', $_POST['text']);
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

This is a **VERY** basic boilerplate and should help you to get started. Tweak it as you go.

Comment: Christian Gärtner has given you a clue about starting point. As I understand you simply want an option to add a text to some page without using a CMS for it. This can be achieved with the use of Christian Gärtner solution, yet you need to save the data in a database or a txt file for instance. Once the form is submitted the text is saved in a file/db and the your page retrieves this text from the db and shows on the page

Comment: thanks for your answers! Well but i have to say that i dont have a database for access. I mean isn't it possible like this way:

`editor.html` -> `current.txt` -> `content.php` like in my example! It reads the content of a txt-file and does not need any db! Therefore i only need to say the `WYSIWYG` should write a txt on submit!

Comment: Yeah this is possible as well. You should not see a "database" as sql. SQL is a type of database. If you need a flatfile database you can go with this.

Comment: but than as the last question you could possibly answer. How can i tell a wysiwyg-editor to write a `.txt` on `submit`, thanks and greets from cologne!

Comment: I' ve edited my answer with a simple setup. Greets from Hamburg :D

Comment: Make sure that you have a PHP enabled webserver. P.S. gerne!

Comment: i am using xampp and get this error `Permission denied in ../htdocs/txtprocess/process.php on line 4` the password in your example i have to type in is `your_password` isnt it?

Comment: That is a "problem" with the system and not of the script it self. You have to make sure that the xampp user (in most cases something like `www-data`) can write and read the file. In UNIX system something like `755` should be fine. With Windows I am not too familiar.

Comment: i uploaded it on my webspace and it works like a charm! big thanks to you, its what i wanted to!